# Problem with the size of the Twitter image

Tags: android, twitter

I have used this [code](http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/05/android-programming-tutorial-a-simple-twitter-feed-reader/) to get a feed reader form twitter. I have list them in the listView as the article says, but with some images I have a problem with the size and they are anormally big...I have tried unsuccesfully to fix the size of the image with:

```
<ImageView  android:id="@+id/photoUser" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:maxWidth="10dp" android:maxHeight="10dp"
android:paddingRight="12dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange that the code didn't do that for me when I wrote it. What android version are you testing on?

For one reason or another, I've found that often only specifying maxWidth/maxHeight doesn't behave as you would expect, and I also have to specify minWidth/minHeight to effectively control image size. I had to do exactly that in a follow-up [development tutorial](http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/06/android-development-tutorial-progressbar-example/) to the post you reference.

Give something like this a try:

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/photoUser"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:maxWidth="30dip"
 android:minWidth="30dip"
 android:maxHeight="30dip"
 android:minHeight="30dip"
 android:paddingRight="12dip" />
```

Comment: I actually solved it resizing the image by code. Like is done here http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html